# Merge two files based on a mapping in a third file

Tags: unix, join, awk

I need to merge two files based on a mapping that is contained in another file. So in the example below, join file1 with file2 where column 2 in file1 matches column 2 in file3 AND column 2 in file2 matches column 4 in file3.

Preferably a solution that utilises unix programs such as awk etc.

file1:

```
Scf_3L  12798910    T   0   41  0   0   NA  NA
Scf_3L  12798911    C   0   0   43  0   NA  NA
Scf_3L  12798912    A   42  0   0   0   NA  NA
Scf_3L  12798913    G   0   0   0   44  NA  NA
Scf_3L  12798914    T   0   42  0   0   NA  NA
Scf_3L  12798915    G   0   0   0   44  NA  NA
Scf_3L  12798916    T   0   42  0   0   NA  NA
Scf_3L  12798917    A   41  0   0   0   NA  NA
Scf_3L  12798918    G   0   0   0   43  NA  NA
Scf_3L  12798919    T   0   43  0   0   NA  NA
Scf_3L  12798920    T   0   41  0   0   NA  NA
```

file2:

```
3L  12559896    T   0   31  0   0   NA  NA
3L  12559897    C   0   0   33  0   NA  NA
3L  12559898    A   34  0   0   0   NA  NA
3L  12559899    G   0   0   0   33  NA  NA
3L  12559900    T   0   34  0   0   NA  NA
3L  12559901    G   0   0   0   33  NA  NA
3L  12559902    T   0   33  0   0   NA  NA
3L  12559903    A   33  0   0   0   NA  NA
3L  12559904    G   0   0   0   33  NA  NA
3L  12559905    T   0   34  0   0   NA  NA
3L  12559906    T   0   33  0   0   NA  NA
```

file3:

```
3L  12798910    T   12559896    T
3L  12798911    C   12559897    C
3L  12798912    A   12559898    A
3L  12798913    G   12559899    G
3L  12798914    T   12559900    T
3L  12798915    G   12559901    G
3L  12798916    T   12559902    T
3L  12798917    A   12559903    A
3L  12798918    G   12559904    G
3L  12798919    T   12559905    T
3L  12798920    T   12559906    T
```

output:

```
Scf_3L  12798910    T   0   41  0   0   NA  NA    3L    12559896    T   0   31  0   0   NA  NA
Scf_3L  12798911    C   0   0   43  0   NA  NA    3L    12559897    C   0   0   33  0   NA  NA
Scf_3L  12798912    A   42  0   0   0   NA  NA    3L    12559898    A   34  0   0   0   NA  NA
Scf_3L  12798913    G   0   0   0   44  NA  NA    3L    12559899    G   0   0   0   33  NA  NA
Scf_3L  12798914    T   0   42  0   0   NA  NA    3L    12559900    T   0   34  0   0   NA  NA
Scf_3L  12798915    G   0   0   0   44  NA  NA    3L    12559901    G   0   0   0   33  NA  NA
Scf_3L  12798916    T   0   42  0   0   NA  NA    3L    12559902    T   0   33  0   0   NA  NA
Scf_3L  12798917    A   41  0   0   0   NA  NA    3L    12559903    A   33  0   0   0   NA  NA
Scf_3L  12798918    G   0   0   0   43  NA  NA    3L    12559904    G   0   0   0   33  NA  NA
Scf_3L  12798919    T   0   43  0   0   NA  NA    3L    12559905    T   0   34  0   0   NA  NA
Scf_3L  12798920    T   0   41  0   0   NA  NA    3L    12559906    T   0   33  0   0   NA  NA
```

Comment: You have chosen proper tools (`awk`). Show us your efforts ?

Comment: This does not seem like a question, merely a search for a working solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this was originally looking for an answer using UNIX built-ins I opted to use perl and a nice solution can be found here: [Merge files based on a mapping in another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43821468/merge-files-based-on-a-mapping-in-another-file)

Answer (score 2):

You can use two incantations of the `join` command:

```
join -o1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,1.10,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8,2.9 -1 1 -2 2 <(join -o 2.4,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2.1,2.2,2.3 -1 2 -2 2 file1 file3) file2
```

The option `-o` just lists the fields of the output.

The inner `join` joins `file1` with the mapping `file3` and provides the key for the second outer join with `file2`

If the sequence of columns is not important you can skip the `-o` options and use something like :

```
join -1 12 -2 2 <(join  -1 2 -2 2 file1 file3 ) file2
```